# Remove gem installed via Bundler from Git/Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bundler, rbenv

In my Rails app, I have installed the gem `sdoc` from Github by specifying `gem 'sdoc', github: 'voloko/sdoc'` in my `Gemfile`. All was well until I recently updated Bundler to v1.6.0.rc.

Now I get the following error message when Bundler tries to load the gem:

```
There was a LoadError while loading sdoc.gemspec: 
cannot infer basepath from
  /Users/manuel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/sdoc-1a0e80c2d629/sdoc.gemspec:2:in `require_relative'

Does it try to require a relative path? That's been removed in Ruby 1.9.
```

I've already fixed the issue and [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/voloko/sdoc/pull/73), but I cannot get rid of the "broken" gem!

This is what I tried:

- removing the gem from the `Gemfile` or setting it to a different version
- removing `Gemfile.lock`
- deleting the gem folder `/Users/manuel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/sdoc-1a0e80c2d629`
- `gem uninstall sdoc` (It doesn't even appear in `gem list`)

Nothing helped, every time I do `bundle install` or `bundle update` afterwards, I get the same error.

Any hints?

Comment: Deleting `Gemfile.lock` doesn't help either unfortunately, same error. Added it to the list...

Comment: Please bring back `Gemfile.lock`, I suggested editing and removing references to a gem you wanted to delete from a project that had problems.

Comment: @dachi Can you elaborate? You want me to edit `Gemfile.lock` and remove all references to `sdoc`?

Comment: Remove from `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`. If not try looking into `Gemfile.lock` I guess it's a dependency of another Gem.

Comment: No, it's not a dependency of another gem, it's in my `Gemfile`. Removing it and running `bundle install` generates the same error.

Comment: I edited my question to make this more clear.

Comment: I can't say anything more but to try manually `rbenv rehash` but bundler should do it automatically I guess.

Comment: `rbenv rehash` generates shims... has nothing to do with my problem AFAICS.

Answer (score 3):

#### First-off: Clarifying a few things

From the [Bundler documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.7/git.html):

> Because Rubygems lacks the ability to handle gems from git, any gems installed from a git repository will not show up in gem list. They will, however, be available after running Bundler.setup

Also, after deleting the gem inside the `. . . /bundler/gems/` directory, you also should run `rbenv rehash`. This should get rid of the gem for you.

---

### Answer:

Go to the root directory *of your project* (where the Gemfile resides) and run `bundle clean`. You have to pass either `--path` or `--force` switches. This should remove gems installed via *git* (usually **if** you have those gems installed and listed by `gem list`).

If you have issues. Delete the directories manually as you already tried and run `rbenv rehash`.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would downgrade Bundler (ie. uninstall the RC release and install the latest stable).

Comment: Yep, that would probably work as a workaround... still would be interesting to know how to uninstall these gems. :)